# How to scope a function to a certain module?

Tags: powershell

I have `main.ps1` and `module.psm1`. `module.psm1` is a class module and a function. The function is `Read-Host`. I had to override it to return `'y'` when called within an instance of `module.psm1`.

Now, in `main.ps1`, I'd like to use `Read-Host` with its default behavior (prompt the user.) Is there a way to do that? Or a way to confine `Read-Host` override function to the scope of that module only?

Thank you.

Comment: `I had to override it to return 'y' ...`  Smells a bit [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  What are you actually doing where the 'solution' is to over-ride a common built-in cmdlet?

Comment: Trying to automate a script that require 'y' from the user in that specific module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might address the original `Read-Host` function with a *module-qualified* function path:

Without the custom `Read-Host` function:

```
Read-Host 'Native Read-Host'
Native Read-Host:

Get-Command Read-Host

CommandType     Name             Version    Source
-----------     ----             -------    ------
Cmdlet          Read-Host        7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
```

Creating your custom function:

```
function Read-Host { Write-Host 'Custom Read-Host' }

Read-Host
Custom Read-Host

Get-Command Read-Host

CommandType     Name             Version    Source
-----------     ----             -------    ------
Cmdlet          Read-Host
```

Now using the module-qualified function path (`Source` property of the native `Read-Host` command):

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Read-Host 'Native Read-Host'
Native Read-Host:
```

Comment: I can't modify the script that uses Read-Host inside the module (.psm1) I need to scope functionality of the custom Read-Host to inside .psm1 class. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @jsnoobie You don't need to modify the module script for this solution. This code goes into your main.ps1. You only have to change calls to `Read-Host` in your main.ps1 to the fully-qualified name `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Read-Host`.

Answer (score 1):

- **If you have control over the `.psm1` file**:

  - **Make the overridden `Read-Host` function *private* to your module, by *not exporting it***; that way, only functions *in the same module* see the overridden definition, unlike importers of your module.
  - Since *all* functions defined in a `.psm1` file (that doesn't have an associated module manifest, `.psd1`) are exported by default, you need an [`Export-ModuleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember) call to *limit* what functions are exported; in this call, enumerate the names of all functions you *do* want to export (to be visible an importer) and do *not* include `Read-Host`; e.g., if you want to export functions `Get-Foo` and `Set-Foo`, place the following at the *bottom* of `module.psm1`:

    ```bash
     Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-Foo, Set-Foo
    ```

    - You can also use *wildcard* expression:

      ```bash
       Export-ModuleMember -Function *-Foo
      ```
- **Otherwise**:

  - Remove your module once you no longer need it (you can re-import it later; you could even remove the `Read-Host` function with `Remove-Item Function:Read-Host`, though modifying a loaded module's state that way seems tricky):

    ```bash
    Remove-Module module # After this, Read-Host has its original meaning
    ```
  - Alternatively, if modifying the `Read-Host` call in `main.ps1` is an option, use a *module-qualified* invocation (`Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Read-Host`), as shown in [iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72621695/45375)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by commenter, this is not recommended. The module function should be refactored by **adding an optional parameter** that allows callers to provide a choice programmatically.

If you really can't modify the source of the module, then here are two ways to temporarily override `Read-Host`.

For testing both solutions I have created the following module file:

**module.psm1**

```sh
Function ModuleFun {
    $choice = Read-Host 'Enter (Y)es or (N)o' 
    "Output from module: $choice"
}
```

### 1st solution

The easiest solution is possible when you have [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester) installed. I've tested it with Pester 5 but I believe it should work with older Pester versions too. It uses the [InModuleScope](https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/commands/InModuleScope) command of Pester to "hack" a module.

**main.ps1**

```sh
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\module.psm1

# InModuleScope is provided by Pester.
# Override Read-Host within module scope only.
InModuleScope -ModuleName module -ScriptBlock {
    Function Script:Read-Host { $global:ReadHostOverride }
}

# Use Read-Host normally
Read-Host 'Enter something'

# Call module function with overridden Read-Host 
$ReadHostOverride = 'Y'
ModuleFun

# Use Read-Host normally again
Read-Host 'Enter something'

# Call module function with different Read-Host override value
$ReadHostOverride = 'N'
ModuleFun
```

**Output:**

```text
Enter something: 23
23
Output from module: Y
Enter something: 42  
42
Output from module: N
```

---

### 2nd solution

If you don't have Pester available, you may use my function `Invoke-WithReadHostOverride` to override `Read-Host` during the execution of a script block that calls a module function.

**main.ps1**

```sh
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\module.psm1

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create an in-memory module which has the advantage that the dot sourcing operator "." 
# allows us to run a scriptblock in the caller's scope (outside of the module). 
# You may put this code into a separate module file instead.
$null = New-Module {

    # Helper function to call the given script block while Read-Host is overridden
    Function Invoke-WithReadHostOverride {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $ReadHostOutput,
            [Parameter(Mandatory)] [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
        )

        # Temporary override of Read-Host command, returns value given by parameter.
        Function Global:Read-Host { $ReadHostOutput }

        try {
            # Everything in ScriptBlock calls our Read-Host override
            . $ScriptBlock
        }
        finally {
            # Remove our Read-Host override again
            Remove-Item Function:Read-Host
        }
    }
}

#------------ DEMO CODE --------------------------------------------------------------

# Use Read-Host normally
Read-Host 'Enter something'

# Call module function with overridden Read-Host 
Invoke-WithReadHostOverride -ReadHostOutput Y -ScriptBlock {
    $choice = ModuleFun
}

$choice  # Thanks to the in-memory module trick, $choice has been set in current scope!

# Use Read-Host normally again
Read-Host 'Enter something'

# Call module function with different Read-Host override value
Invoke-WithReadHostOverride -ReadHostOutput N -ScriptBlock {
    ModuleFun
}
```

**Output:**

```text
Enter something: 23
23
Output from module: Y
Enter something: 42
42
Output from module: N
```

As usual with such temporary things, it's a good idea to wrap them in `try`/`finally` blocks to ensure the cleanup runs even in case of an exception.

The override works, because **functions have higher precedence than cmdlets** defined in the same session. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7.2):

> If you do not specify a path, PowerShell uses the following precedence
> order when it runs commands for all items loaded in the current
> session:
>
> Alias Function Cmdlet External executable files (programs and
> non-PowerShell scripts)

Comment: Thank you but my question was about having to use Read-Host in .ps1 again where the input of the user is needed. If I use Read-Host in .ps1 right now, it will by 'y' automatically. How do I go around that?

Comment: @jsnoobie I've improved the code so you can override `Read-Host` for a module function multiple times and use normal `Read-Host` in main.ps1. See demo code.

Comment: @jsnoobie I've found an easier solution, see "1st solution".